# Set HTTP body using HTTPService class in the Adobe Air

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flex3

I need to send a byte array of data as a HTTP body using HTTPService class in the Adobe Air API. Can anyone suggest me the way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var encodedString : String = Base64.encode( imageByteArray );  
var service : HTTPService = new HTTPService();
service.method = "POST";  
service.contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';  
service.url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/upload.php';         
var variables : URLVariables = new URLVariables();      
variables.imageArray = encodedString;  
variables.variable2 = "some text string";  
variables.variable3 = "some more text";             
service.send( variables );
```

Base64 class get from
http://code.google.com/p/jpauclair-blog/source/browse/trunk/Experiment/Base64/src/Base64.as